# How to create two side-by-side full-sized textareas using divs

Tags: html, css, layout, textarea

My objective is to create two side-by-side full-sized textareas using divs as illustrated below:

[image]

I can do this easily using a table as the layout mechanism, but I have struggled to try to get it to work using straight div and css. I have also tried using flexbox and bootstrap layouts. I got close, but issues with vertical growth and page level cropped content always arose. Below is the current implementation, and I was wondering how to re-implement using divs:

```
<html>
    <body>
        <table style="width:100%;height:100%;">
            <tr>
                <td>label 1</td>
                <td>label 2</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td style="width:50%;height:100%;">
                    <textarea style="width:100%;height:100%;"></textarea>                   
                </td>
                <td style="width:50%;height:100%;">
                    <textarea style="width:100%;height:100%;"></textarea>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="2">
                    <button>button 1</button>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

change the width to 49% to for both text areas.

Comment: unfortunately this does not work. Setting cols="30" rows="10" does not achieve the textareas filling all available area as does the table layout solution, nor does trying to set "height="100%" on the textareas. The other comment about changing the width to 49% doesn't affect vertical layout at all.

Answer (score 0):

you can achieve this using flexbox:

```
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="form-item">
    <label>Item 1</label>
    <textarea name="" id="" cols="30" rows="10"></textarea>
  </div>
  <div class="form-item">
    <label>Item 2</label>
    <textarea name=""></textarea>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.wrap {
  display: flex;
}

.form-item {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 50%;
}

.form-item label {
  display: block;
}
```

Does this solve the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```css
.wrapper{
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
}
.item-wrapper{
  width: 48%;
  margin-right: 10px;
}
textarea{
  width: 100%;
}
label{
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="item-wrapper">
    <label>label 1</label>
    <textarea rows="10"></textarea>
  </div>
  <div class="item-wrapper">
    <label>label 2</label>
    <textarea rows="10"></textarea>
  </div>
</div>

<button>button 1</button>
```

Comment: This is very similar to the original proposed solution, and also does not work, given that settings rows=10 on both textareas does not result in a textarea that expands to fill all available space. I think it would be best if we try out the code in a simple local index.html and verify the textareas expand to fill all remaining space before posting answers.